Can logic exist outside of a linguistic framework?
Can humans logic/reasoning exist despite the lack of symbols of communicating it?
My point also ask two other follow-up questions can logic exist devoid of a mind (be it natural i.e., materialistic or artificial)? and is logic inherent to life and tying this to evolution at what point down the evolutionary tree do we say logic stops existing i.e., when does "logic" start become just instinctual and not a voluntary emergent phenomenon of a living being?


Logic can be formulated without symbols but not without technical
terms like proposition, implication, truth, false, …
The rules of a calculus of logic has been wired into smart artifical
systems. Systems to which one does not ascribe a mind, i.e. mental capabilities.
Of course, there have been human programmers with the corresponding
mental capabilities.
During the biological evolution the development of logic presupposes
a certain degree of mental capabilities of a brain and its neural
network. But the phylogenesis of logical capabilites of animals has
developed bottom-up.


"the phylogenesis of logical capabilites of animals has developed bottom-up." This is not really true. Put whatever primitive organism you can think of in a closed box with nothing else in it and for any length of time and I think it is clear that you we will not see any logical capability evolve.

@Speakpigeon The driving force of bottom-up development is the interaction with the environment during the biological evolution. In a closed box there is no environment by definition.

"In a closed box there is no environment by definition." Exactly, which is why it's not really "bottom-up". It's natural selection which does the real job, I think.

@Speakpigeon I agree: Natural selection together with the other basic mechanisms, e.g., variability, which trigger the biological evolution.
